# Should we warn user that posted code is not matching standard/guidelines

Tags: discussion, answers

Different programming languages and platforms like Android have general guidelines to name member, methods and so on.

A lot of users post questions with code that didn't match guidelines.

**Should we warn them about it ?**

[Example where user didn't wan't IDE spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141453/how-to-stop-android-studio-adding-spaces-to-my-code)

Comment: IMO the best way would be to provide the answer for their question and in that include the notice about the guideline. esp if the answer is influenced by that guideline.

Comment: Should I flag this question as Primarly Opinion based ?

Comment: @Trobbins I was thinking about this meta question

Answer (score 13):

Coding style is subjective and largely a matter of personal preference. So there is usually no right or wrong. Even when formal guidelines exist.

And even in that case, there might be reasons why someone deviates from them, such as a local company coding standard.

Nagging about coding standards when someone is seeking help for a specific problem, which in itself is not related to coding style, is not helpful and will only create conflict.

Answer (score 5):

Note: originally I hadn't looked at the referenced question. I wouldn't answer a question like that, but I see a *lot* of questions which aren't asking about style, but which violate the conventions of the context.

Assuming this is a language or platform with very clearly defined and well-adopted conventions, I think it's entirely reasonable to gently suggest that a poster should follow those conventions. I *wouldn't* start trying to apply whitespace or bracing conventions, but naming conventions are a different matter.

I can see four broad situations in which this happens:

- **The poster is aware of the conventions, but couldn't be bothered to follow them when creating code for the post.**
  The post would be better if it followed the conventions, as that would reduce friction for anyone trying to understand it (either as a question or an answer.)
- **The poster is unaware of the conventions.**
  Educating them will not only help them get into good habits, but it will *also* improve the quality of the post.
- **The poster is aware of the convention, but their local situation doesn't follow it, for no good reason.**
  The poor practice in their local situation is *not* a good reason to propagate the lack of following the convention in a Stack Overflow post, and it's possible that applying that very small amount of pressure may eventually change the local practice to a better one.
- **The poster is aware of the convention, but their local situation doesn't follow it, for a good reason. (Very rare.)**
  Again, the poor practice in their local situation doesn't excuse the propagation - and no active *harm* done in reminding the poster of this.

Basically, I see no harm in doing so, so long as it doesn't distract from the post itself, and so long as it's done in a friendly manner. A great deal of *good* can come from it, getting new programmers into good habits early on.

Additionally, note the important theme here that we're talking about *code on Stack Overflow*. This isn't code in your company project - it's code on Stack Overflow, and it's going to be read by far more people *outside* your company than *inside* your company... so you should code according to that requirement. If you're too lazy to undo your company's convention violations, then I have no problem in calling you out on that :)

Comment: I totally agree with you and other answer. As I'm developping with Android SDK, the standard is very clear about it : http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions but most questions in Android tag have very poor quality

Comment: One way I see people "gently suggest" better coding style is by using better coding style in their answer. I think this is often the most productive way to approach the problem. One could even include a simple explanation of the style choices they made in their answer.

Comment: The whole problem with this attitude is: then you should also nag on every single user who can't use English properly. And if we would do that, SO would soon become a grammar site and not a programming site. All your arguments about coding style could as well be applied to English. Unawareness is not an excuse to not learn etc etc.

Comment: @Lundin: Your comment explains exactly why we wouldn't do this: this is a programming site, not an English site. People don't come here to get better at English - they *do* come here to get better at programming. Another significant difference is that while I'm happy to fix up people's English with edits, I would usually only change actual typos within the code samples - not their style.

Comment: Your argument was that code of Stack Overflow should follow certain conventions because it is a public site, in which case I don't see why the same wouldn't apply to English as well. People may come here looking for programming, but if they can't interpret what is said in a post because it was written in crappy English, then how will their programming skills improve?

Comment: @Lundin: Right, and that's why we edit posts with bad English in, assuming we can understand it. One difference between poor code style and poor English style: poor naming in code adds friction but doesn't make the code impossible to understand in terms of what it will do (although it may well make it impossible to understand what it's *trying* to do). If the English is very, very broken it can often be impossible to fix up. And of course in extreme cases people *do* already comment on natural language style - anyone posting an all-caps question will be asked not to.

Comment: IThinkItIsQuitePossibleToHaveTroubleUnderstandingCodeJustBecauseItIsUsingACodingStyleWhichIsNotConventionOrSimplyBecauseImNotUsedToIt. :)  In that case should we edit such code just as we edit English? The main problem with that is: it is not always obvious what is convention and what is not. Someone will come up with their own personal belief of what's proper coding style and then run around vandal-editing other people's posts, we already see that happening now and then.

Comment: @Lundin: And that's why I'm suggesting that common sense should prevail here. I don't think it's right to actually edit someone's code except for typos, but I think it's reasonable to point out when they have gone against the *published, universally-adopted* style for a language/platform. You keep giving examples of where it would be unreasonable, assuming that everyone will take it to an extreme. How do you feel about the more sensible cases, where it's just a matter of informing an OP politely that their code would be more readable to others if they followed the universal convention?

Answer (score 3):

Of course not! Coding standards/guidelines are made at first by the publishers of the language.

But Software Engineers, Developers, Coders, Programmers, and also Students and Teachers, they have their own unique way of standards also guidelines.

Some people like using the `{` for method names as follows in two different ways.

```
public void methodName() {
   // method body
}


public void methodName()
{
   // method body
}
```

Some companies forces the developers to use one out of the above two mentioned methods. And also about the code indentation.

But going to **warning might be unnecessary burden to the user who tries to post a question or an answer!**.

Comment: Would that apply if it were `public void METHOD__NAME()` as well? Can you not see the potential benefit in raising someone's awareness of common conventions?

Comment: The example you take, have both acceptable format in coding standards. No body have problem in that case.  Problem raise where poster did not use any coding standards or poor standards?

Comment: JonSkeet and @have-no-display-name I agree with you both! But then how can warn someone as the standards and guidelines might be limitless! don't you think? So in that case the Poster will get into more troublesome situation! We can do something like this, let the Editors should see what are the poor standards that a poster might have used and let them edit in accordingly.